# Run aws cli from EC2 python script with variables

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I need to run AWS CLI Polly service from AWS EC2 using python, with additional variables. The problem is with the including variable in the cmd string

```
import subprocess
row1 = 'My husband and I have done around 100 rooms and came to Barcelona as it has a reputation for top class rooms. We did Bajo Zero based on a recommendation from an escape room enthusiast in the UK and werent disappointed. It was a very well made immersive room with some clever puzzles. We chose hard mode and it was quite challenging as a pair but we did make it out in time. ,Escapem Elements Aire Escape Room'
cmd = 'aws polly synthesize-speech --output-format mp3 --engine neural --voice-id Kevin --text' +row1+ 'speech1.mp3'

subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

This script command is executed from withing EC2 NOT local

Comment: AWS provides an SDK for Python: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/polly.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than calling the `aws` program from Python, you can use the [boto3 library](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/quickstart.html) to directly call AWS. In fact, the AWS CLI is written in Python and uses this library too!

You can then [use boto3 to call Polly](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/polly.html).

For example:

```py
import boto3

client = boto3.client('polly')

response = client.synthesize_speech(
    Engine='neural',
    LanguageCode='en-US',
    OutputFormat='mp3',
    Text='My husband and I have done around 100 rooms',
    VoiceId='Kevin'
)
```